# Step-wise Multiple Regression or ANCOVA

Tags: self-study, ancova, stepwise-regression

I have an assignment that gives a dataset and a choice of 3 tests: Step-wise Multiple Regression, ANCOVA and Log-Linear Analysis.

The dataset consists of `Blood Pressure` measurements as the dependent variable (DV), and `Smoking` (True/False) as the independent variable (IV) with confounders being `Age` and `Gender`. My hypothesis is that smoking increases blood pressure but being a man or being older would make blood pressure increase too.

I have ruled out Log-Linear Analysis, but I am getting confused which of the other tests would be more appropriate. If it was just `Age` as a confounder I would do ANCOVA as it is a continuous covariate but I'm not sure what to do with `Gender` as it's categorical. As I understand it, ANCOVA and Multiple Regression are identical mathematically so the distinction and implementation is making me completely lost!

Would greatly appreciate if anyone could help me clear this up?
Thank you

Comment: As an aside, I'll never understand why teachers assign questions like this.  It's never really important to be able to distinguish between a "multiple regression" model or "ANCOVA" model in the real word, for example.  What's important is that you are able to state your model and ensure that the data you've collected are appropriate for your model and it's assumptions.  Too much time is wasted focusing on this type of minutiae.

Comment: To help you answer this question, consider if one of your model choices is a subset of the other.

Comment: Couldn't agree more, to put it in context it's a Masters level stats class that has not touched regression or the concept of modelling at all. Thanks for the edit!

Comment: Hopefully my second comment helped you out a bit more.  Is it clear now?  The first one was just me venting ;-).

Comment: I think ANCOVA is a subset of multiple regression and so if my model uses categorical predictors like gender and continuous predictors like age, I can just call it multiple regression and do it in a step-wise way to make my lecturer happy? Am I on the right lines?

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Definitely needed some confirmation. Step-wise or not will give the same result in the end right? Could you explain when you would call it ANCOVA and when you would call it multiple regression?

Comment: So smoking and gender effect on blood pressure could be seen as ANCOVA because they are categorical but with the addition of age it would be multiple regression?

Comment: So I may have misled you with my previous comment so I'm going to give you a common definition that you'll find for ANCOVA "ANCOVA evaluates whether the means of a dependent variable (DV) are equal across levels of a categorical independent variable (IV) often called a treatment, while statistically controlling for the effects of other continuous variables that are not of primary interest, known as covariates (CV) or nuisance variables (wikipedia)."  In the scenario you describe using this definition, it is ANCOVA.